# How to write multiple .csv files from a list of data frames into a new folder with the original filename?

Tags: r, csv, tidyverse, readr

As the subject suggests, I'm trying to write a list of data frames into a new folder so, that the original name stays same as the original file (and so that the original files don't get overwritten in the original folder!). Tried the code below, but simply didn't get the syntax working:

```
sapply(names(points_calculated), 
       function (x) write_csv(points_calculated[[x]], file=paste("./ExperimentFolder/PointsFolder", x)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that `points_calculated` is a list of data.frames, and the `names(points_calculated)` are the filename you want, you can do the following:

```r
library(purrr)
points_calculated %>%
  iwalk(
    ~ readr::write_csv(.x, file = paste("./ExperimentFolder/PointsFolder", .y))
  )
)
```

`imap()` will iterate over your list, and perform the function after `~`. `.x` is the element of the list (the data.frame), and `.y` is it's name.